# Record video with MediaCodec and google assistant enabled in Android

Tags: android, video-capture, android-mediacodec, google-assistant-sdk

I'm trying to record a video (image and audio) using MediaCodec. But when Google Assistant is enabled sometimes occurs this error and the screen freezes.

> 02-27 21:54:53.774 398-8943/? E/APM_AudioPolicyManager: startInput(1686) failed: other input 1678 already started
>   02-27 21:54:53.775 3897-4556/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error -38 during AudioRecord native read
>   02-27 21:54:53.776 3897-4556/? E/AudioProvider: audioRecord read failed
>                                                   com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393221 | not open
>                                                       at com.google.android.libraries.assistant.hotword.a.a(SourceFile:67)
>                                                       at com.google.android.libraries.assistant.hotword.b.run(SourceFile:30)
>                                                       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
>                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
>                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
>                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>   02-27 21:54:53.780 398-18122/? E/msm8916_platform: voice_extn_compress_voip_is_active: COMPRESS_VOIP_ENABLED is not defined
>   02-27 21:54:53.781 398-18122/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
>   02-27 21:54:53.825 398-790/? E/APM_AudioPolicyManager: startInput(1694) failed: other input 1678 already started
>   02-27 21:54:53.825 3897-8904/? E/AudioRecord: start() status -38
>   02-27 21:54:53.826 3897-8904/? E/AudioProvider: recording stopped, not in RECORDSTATE_RECORDING state

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you doing screen recording? Seems like a similar problem to other screen recording apps like AZ Screen Recorder.

Comment: No, I'm trying to record capturing the camera.